# Example of Continuations in Scheme

Tags: scheme, continuations

I'm having some trouble understanding this piece of code that my professor used as example:

```
(define saved-cont #f)  

(define (test-cont)
     (let ((x 0))
      (call/cc
       (lambda (k)     
        (set! saved-cont k))) 

      (set! x (+ x 1))
      (display x)
      (newline)))
```

If we run for the first time `(test-cont)` what does `k` contain?

Note: I'm using R6RS Scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call/cc` calls the given function with the current continuation as its sole argument. Thus, `k` here is the current continuation. When you call it with a value, the `call/cc` will return with the value you gave. (Though, since you're not using `call/cc`'s return value in your code above, and since R6RS allows zero-valued returns in that case, you can just call `saved-cont` with no arguments and still do what you expect.)

Here, basically, every time you call `(saved-cont)`, the code below the `call/cc` will run again. Thus, `x` will increment, and its new value will display.